# Hibernate HQL with interfaces

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, entity

According to this section of the Hibernate documentation I should be able to query any java class in HQL

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-polymorphism

Unfortunately when I run this query...

```
"from Transaction trans where trans.envelopeId=:envelopeId"
```

I get the message "Transaction is not mapped [from Transaction trans where trans.envelopeId=:envelopeId]".

Transaction is an interface, I have to entity classes that implement it, I want on HQL query to return a Collection of type Transaction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, according to the Hibernate documentation on [Polymorphic queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-polymorphism):

> Hibernate queries can name any Java
>   class or interface in the from clause.
>   The query will return instances of all
>   persistent classes that extend that
>   class or implement the interface. The
>   following query would return all
>   persistent objects:
>
> ```
> from java.lang.Object o
> ```
>
> The interface Named might be
>   implemented by various persistent
>   classes:
>
> ```
> from Named n, Named m where n.name = m.name
> ```

But because the interface is not mapped (and thus unknown), you need to use the fully qualified name in your HQL query:

```
from qualified.name.Transaction trans where trans.envelopeId=:envelopeId
```

This **will** return instances of all persistent classes that implement your `Transaction` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the interfaces so you don't have to specify the full path. I use a file called imports.hbm.xml to handle all interfaces:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com...path.to.implementations">
  <import class="com.path.to.interfaces.Transaction" rename="Transaction"/>
...
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then add that to the configuration just like a normal mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to map the interface as the parent class and the implementing classes as its subclass.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#inheritance-strategies

Comment: You can't map an interface AFAIK.

Comment: The docs say you can. <class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT"> (Payment is an interface).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, JPA can't but Hibernate can (http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4413). Anyway, you don't need to.