# Query using value from nested interface as parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been reading a lot about using enums as parameters in queries. I have some queries in my project that use the value from these enums as parameters.

For example:

```
public enum YesNo {
Y, N
}
```

Query:

```
select ent 
from 
       Entity ent 
where
       ent.id = :id
       and ent.deleted = project.path.example.YesNo.N
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Entity{
Long id;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
YesNo deleted;
}
```

The above **works** correctly as expected.

However, when I have the following:

```
interface Commons{
    interface MostCommonTypesofAnimals {
        long DOG = 1L;
        long CAT = 2L;
    }
}
```

Query

```
select a 
from 
       Animal a 
where
       a.id = :id
       and a.type = project.path.example.Commons.MostCommonTypesofAnimals.DOG
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Animal{
Long id;
Type type;
}

@Entity
public class Type{
public Long id;
}
```

It does not work telling me that the path is incorrect even though it is actually correct.

Is there any work around? Or interface values cannot be mapped? Can anyone provide me an example that works? I could not find anything similar.

Please note that this is just an example to illustrate the situation., those are not the real names that I am using or anything.

Answer (score 1):

For using enum while using hibernate / jpa (based on your tags), you should use annotation in your Pojo class.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
```

In your example, something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableName")
public class entityName {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private YesNo yesNoEnum;
}
```

The annotation can go here or in the getter, as you prefer.

You can find more info [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/)

ps: for yes or no I suggest you using a boolean value, not an enum

Comment: Hello, @Leviand! Actually, when I use Enums, it's working as expected. The problem is when I am using an interface which has some variables on it. Check the interface Commons.

Comment: there's a concept error then: if your table is "animal", that should be represented by a class, not an interface. Try to rework your code in that way. And also if you are using an interface into another one, use instead _extends_

Comment: My entity class is Animal. My interface class which is Commons, has another interface on it, named Animals.

Comment: Or: If you want to use the _Animals_ as a value for queries, transform that into Enum, and set the enum to _EnumType.ORDINAL_

Comment: What I asked is if there is a way to use an interface value as an enum in a query.

Comment: Can this helps you somehow ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301329/1984767

Comment: Thanks, I will give a look into that.